# can firebase cloud functions handle 100K+ requests at the same time?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

my app may have 100K+ Users active at same time so can Firebase - Cloud Functions & Firestore handle that traffic.

Not getting a clear answer from firebase documentation.

Comment: Search "Cloud Functions scaling" on Google and the first result is [Using maximum instances](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/max-instances#limits_best_practices) where you find *the number of simultaneous instances that your function might have is effectively unlimited unless you've configured such a limit*. I have downvoted your answer because *This question does not show any research effort*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have as many instances as you need! For example in documentation (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/max-instances) they give an example of 3000 instances, but state there is no upper limit.

And if you are using v2, each instance can have up to 1k simultaneous runs (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/concurrency)

So, except if you have limited billing capabilities on your account, there is no limit!

Comment: So, if i have not specified a max limit then it will scale automatically ?

Comment: Yes, just take care of the billing!